# TailwindCSS with Laravel colors don't work

Tags: php, laravel, tailwind-css, laravel-livewire, vite

I'm using Laravel 9 with Tailwind (3.1.8) and LiveWire Powergrid.

While trying to change color of `Edit` and `Delete` button in Powergrid datatable only working class with colors is `"bg-blue-[num]"`. I'm wondering why, because I've got the newest Tailwind version. Nothing is changed in `tailwind.config.js` under `theme` section.

Default function which creates a button at the last columns:

```
 public function actions(): array
        {
           return [
               Button::make('edit', 'Edit')
                   ->class('bg-blue-400 cursor-pointer text-white px-3 py-2.5 m-1 rounded text-sm')
                   ->route('users.edit', ['user' => 'id']),
    
               Button::make('destroy', 'Delete')
                   ->class('bg-red-400 cursor-pointer text-white px-3 py-2.5 m-1 rounded text-sm')
                   ->route('users.destroy', ['user' => 'id'])
                   ->method('delete')
            ];
        }
```

Result:
[image]

Buttons "Delete" are white, but "Edit" are blue. Rest of colors also doesn't work.

I want to remind that I use also Vite.

Tried to use `php artisan config:cache` and `clear` but no results. There's any chance to handle that?

Comment: Are your sure these `.php` files are in `content` section of your tailwind config?

Comment: Are you using Tailwind 3?

Comment: In `tailwind.config.js` I've got `content` section with path to `./resources/views/**/*.blade.php`. Also added the path to the PowerGrid components which are responsible for drawing the  datatable: `./vendor/power-components/livewire-powergrid/resources/views/**/*.blade.php`. I've run `npm run build` and `npm run dev` and it does not help. Is it right thinking?

Answer (score 1):

@Ihar Aliakseyenka was right.

If you use PowerGrid and you surprisingly have half "styles" compiled you should check the `tailwind.config.js`.

Content section should be filled with paths **to all** directories (maybe I'm wrong) which uses **TailwindCSS**.

In my case PowerGrid table was configured and "drawn" via created component called `UserTable.php` inside `App/Http/Livewire` directory.

So I've put the relative path inside the config:

```
content: [
        './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
        './storage/framework/views/*.php',
        './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
        './app/Http/Livewire/*.php',
    ],
```

After saving changes, Vite automatically loaded the styles and it started working.

If it couldn't please run `npm run build` and `npm run dev`.

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm run dev` to rebuild the CSS files

Comment: I've done it already and didn't help. What's more I have it running all the time to see changes in real time.

Comment: @kalview If you open the console and manually change one of the edit buttons to bg-red-400 does it show red? Smells like the bg-red-400 class is not be generated for you. I assume the buttons are there but just style text-white bg-white ?

Comment: You mean in the browser like F12? It doesn't change anything. All the 'color' classes except bg-blue-[num] are not generated... :/